# Is there a way to delete any number of objects with the same tag?

Tags: unity-game-engine

There are triangle, square, and circle objects.

When these objects are clicked, prefabs corresponding to the object clicked are created.(If you click on the circle, a circle appears)

All prefabs created in this way, regardless of shape, are bundled with a tag called 'clone'.

```
[SerializeField]
GameObject objectClon;

void OnMouseDown(){
    Instantiate(objectClon, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
}
```

At this time, I want to delete the desired number of desired shapes among the created objects.

To do that, I used Destroy().

```
GameObject[] clone;

clone= GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("clone");
Destroy(clone[n]);
```

However, in this method, only the nth created object is deleted regardless of shape.

How can I delete the shape I want, as many times as I want?

Comment: Loop through the array clone and pick only ones with a name of circle or whatever ?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a new script to identify the shapes:

ShapeType.cs

```cs
public enum ShapeType {
    Circle,
    Triangle,
    Square,
}
public class ShapeIdentifier {
    public ShapeType type;
}
```

Add to each prefab and assign corresponding value in inspector
Then, to get the type of shape:

```cs
clone.GetComponent<ShapeIdentifier>().type == ShapeType.Circle
```

Also, it's worth noting that `FindGameObjectsWithTag()` returns an array of objects, not just a single one, so you could iterate through this array and then destroy based on the type of shape.